# How to convert a ffmpeg command to work with ffmpy?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpy

I am trying to extract a certain audio segment from an entire audio file using ffmpy, which I haven't really worked with before.  So far, I have looked into extracting a certain time range, which suggests to use a command like this:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i input.mp3 -to 00:02:00 -c copy output.mp3`

In my case, I am trying to write a Python script to do this over *multiple* audio files.  Since I am reading from a csv and all that, I am storing important information in variables.  However, being a first time user of ffmpy and ffmpeg I'm really not sure how I'm supposed to do that.

Below is the code that I have so far (including what I attempted to do to so far to extract the audio bits):

```
for line in reader:
        # Get access to the stored file as found in the audio_files dir
        print(line)
        folder_name = line[1].split("/")[len(line[1].split("/")) - 2]
        file_name = line[1].split("/")[len(line[1].split("/")) - 1]

        
        audio_file_path = "./audio_files/" + folder_name + "/" + file_name.split(".")[0] + ".mp3"
        print(audio_file_path)

        start_time = line[2]
        end_time = line[3]

        # Use ffmpy/ffmpeg to extract the audio bits
        ff = FFmpeg(inputs={file_name + ".mp3": "None"}, outputs={file_name + "_truncated.mp3": "None"})
        ff.cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "' + audio_file_path + '" -ss ' + start_time + ' -to ' + end_time + ' -async 1 ' + '"./audio_files/' + folder_name + '/' + file_name.split(".")[0] + '_cut.mp3"'
        print(ff.cmd)
        ff.run()
```

The main issue which I am currently facing is I am having issues running with `ff.run()`.  Even though running the same command on command line (using ffmpeg) seems to go flawlessly, when trying to run with `ffmpy` it gives me "FFRuntime Exited With Status Code 1", and I'm not sure what could be causing this.  As I have only just started using ffmpy and ffmpeg I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing is right, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `ff.cmd` is meant to be for reference only after you construct the command. It is the `FFmpeg()`  call that counts toward constructing the command. In your case, your `ff` creation should look like this:

```
file_name = "spam"
start_time = '02:10'
end_time = '02:19'
ff = FFmpeg(
    inputs={file_name + ".mp3": None},
    outputs={file_name + "_truncated.mp3":
        '-ss ' + start_time + ' -to ' + end_time + ' -async 1 '})

ff.cmd
>> 'ffmpeg -i spam.mp3 -ss 02:10 -to 02:19 -async 1 spam_truncated.mp3'
```

For debugging, the call `ff.run()` takes arguments such as `stdout` and `stderr`, which you can leverage to redirect `ffmpeg`'s output to files:

```
ff.run(
    stdout=open('out.txt', 'w'),
    stderr=open('err.txt', 'w')
)
```

Review the contents of those files to debug your command.

I'd also suggest looking into Python docs for [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pathlib.html) (to construct paths more intuitively) and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for readable string formatting.